# What is the eigenvalue matrix for $A+2I$?

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

Suppose  $A=XDX^{-1}$.

What is the eigenvalue matrix for $A+2I$?

What is the eigenvector matrix?

What is the diagonalisation form of $A+2I=()()()^{-1}$?

**Answer:**

Here  $D$ diagonal matrix of eigenvalues.

If $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are the eigenvalues of $A$, then $\lambda_1+2$ and $\lambda_2+2$ are eigenvalues of $A+2I$.

Thus,

$A+2I=X(D+2I)X^{-1}$.

Am I right?

But then what is the eigenvector matrix for $A+2I$?

Help me

Comment: Hint: Suppose $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$, then is $v$ an eigenvector of $A+2I$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have written down $$A+2I = X(D+2I)X^{-1}$$

That is $$(A+2I)X = X(D+2I)$$

Let $e_i$ be the $i$-th standard unit vector.

$$(A+2I)Xe_i = X(D+2I)e_i$$

$$(A+2I)X_i = X(\lambda_i+2)e_i=(\lambda_i + 2) X_i$$

The columns of $X_i$ are the eigenvectors.

Also, try to prove it directly rather, that is if $Ax=\lambda x$, show that $(A+2I)x=(\lambda + 2) x$.

Comment: the columns of $X_i$ means what?  I think it should be columns of $X$.

Comment: yes, the $i$-th column of $X$..